# Rails and AJAX - how to add parameters after call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

If you click on a photo on Facebook or Instagram, the photo with enlarge (probably) using AJAX and then are appended parameters about the photo to the URL.

How does it work? I would need something similar for menu items, but not sure under which term to search this.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Answer (score -2):

You can change the URL in javascript at any point by just setting `window.location`, regardless of whether you're doing an ajax call or not.  It depends a bit on whether you want navigation to actually take place, or if the javascript is just using the URL to store the values so that it can use them later or in a shared link.  But basically you can do something like:

window.location = 'http://mydomain.com/thispage#param=1,param2=2'

or whatever clever string manipulation you want to create the URL you're looking for.

Comment: `window.location` will have your browser load another page. Question is: how to manipulate history (hence url) during ajax calls (understood: without changing page).

Comment: As far as i know only way to change url through javascript without page reload is changing document.location.hash, or to use HTML5 history API.
I guess javascript frameworks like ember are using this strategy.